# Unexpected EOF and syntax error

Tags: shell, shell-script

I am currently writing my third ever shell script and I have run into a problem. This is my script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "choose one of the following options : \
  1) display all current users \
  2) list all files \
  3) show calendar \
  4) exit script"

while read  
do  
 case in  
        1) who;;  
        2) ls -a;;  
        3) cal;;  
        4) exit;;  
 esac    
done
```

when I try to run the script it says this:

```
line2 : unexpected EOF while looking for matching '"'  
line14 : syntax error: unexpected end of file.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Surely you mean "EOF", not "ECF"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, that your `case` statement is missing the subject - the variable which it should evaluate. Hence you probably want something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cat <<EOD
choose one of the following options:
1) display all current users
2) list all files
3) show calendar
4) exit script
EOD

while true; do
    printf "your choice: "
    read
    case $REPLY in
        1) who;;
        2) ls -a;;
        3) cal;;
        4) exit;;
    esac    
done
```

Here `case` uses the default variable `$REPLY` which `read` fills when it's not given any variable names (see `help read` for details).

Also note the changes: `printf` is used to display the prompt in each round (and doesn't append a newline), `cat` is used to print instructions on several lines so that they don't wrap and are easier to read.

Answer (score 6):

Let's not forget `select`:

```
choices=( 
    "display all current users" 
    "list all files" 
    "show calendar" 
    "exit script"
)
PS3="your choice: "
select choice in "${choices[@]}"; do
    case $choice in
        "${choices[0]}") who;;
        "${choices[1]}") ls -a;;
        "${choices[2]}") cal;;
        "${choices[3]}") break;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: This looks like the cleanest answer so far. It uses select which was designed to do exactly what the OP requires. It puts the choices in an array which is a great way to handle data like this and makes it available for use elsewhere in the script. It uses break rather than exit so the script can do something else after this part is done.

Answer (score 2):

Let us try for a single case initially. I will use `read -p` to read the user input into a variable `opt` followed by case statement as below.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "choose one of the following options : \
  1) display all current users \
  2) list all files \
  3) show calendar \
  4) exit script" opt
case $opt in
1) who;;
2) ls -a;;
3) cal;;
4) exit;;
esac
```

The above script works fine and now, I believe you need to have it in a loop so that you can read user input until the user presses option 4.

So, we could do it with a `while` loop as below. I set the variable `opt` with the initial value as 0. Now, I am iterating in the `while` loop as long as the `opt` variable has a value as 0 (which is why I reset the `opt` variable as 0 at the end of the `case` statement).

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
opt=0;
while [ "$opt" == 0 ]
do
read -p "choose one of the following options : \
  1) display all current users \
  2) list all files \
  3) show calendar \
  4) exit script" opt

case $opt in
1) who;;
2) ls -a;;
3) cal;;
4) exit;;
esac
opt=0
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally put the "while" at the beginning of the code. If you then follow it with a `:`, it will allow it to loop around as many times as you wish.
This is how I would write it.

```
while :
do
    echo "choose one of the following options : \
      1) display all current users \
      2) list all files \
      3) show calendar \
      4) exit script"
    read string
    case $string in
        1)
            who
            ;;
```

then carry on the questions, and end with

```
esac
done
```